# why does the golden ratio, Φ=√(81/80)+√(1/80)+1/2?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, trigonometry

I have been trying to understand the mathematics of the **golden ratio** starting with the following [345](https://stackoverflow.com) relationship.

[image]

Can anybody help me understand why  $ Φ = \sqrt{81/80} + \sqrt{1/80} + 1/2 $ ?

[image]

I think it is something to do with these angles but its quite complicated.

[image]

I know that $ Φ + 1/Φ = \sqrt{5} $  and  $ Φ - 1/Φ = 1 $.

[image]

And also that $ (\sqrt{5} + 2) + (\sqrt{5} - 2) = \sqrt{20} $  and  $ (\sqrt{5} + 2) - (\sqrt{5} - 2) = 4  $.

[image]

Which shows a link to the [metallic means](https://stackoverflow.com) (1 and 4). If anybody can provide any help it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried reducing the radicals $\sqrt{81/80}$ and $\sqrt{1/80}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment: may be this idea helps:

Draw pentagon ABCDE(clock wise, side ED on the bottom) inscribed in a circle.Join A and C to D and E respectively and mark intersection of AD and CE as X. It can be shown that :

$$\frac {AC}{AX}=2 \cos 36^o=\frac{1+\sqrt 5}2=\Phi$$

In this way we must have:

$$\cos 36^o=\sqrt{\frac {81}{320}}+\sqrt{\frac 1{320}}+\sqrt{\frac 1{16}}$$

I think this is easier to show.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Blue:

$$\sqrt{\frac{81}{80}} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{80}}  + \frac12  \ \ \ = \ \ \ \frac{\sqrt{81}}{\sqrt{80}} + \frac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{80}}   + \frac12$$

$$=\frac{9}{\sqrt{80}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{80}}   + \frac12 \ \ \ = \ \ \ \frac{10}{\sqrt{80}} + \frac12$$

$$=\frac{10}{\sqrt{16 \times 5}} + \frac12 \ \ \ = \ \ \ \frac{2 \times \sqrt{5} \times \sqrt{5}}{4 \sqrt{5}} + \frac12=$$

$$=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} + \frac12 \ \ \ = \ \ \ \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \ \ \ = \ \ \ \Phi$$